# Override "project" command in Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a quite heavy project with many modules aka sbt subprojects each of each has a big company name prefix. I've tried to find `project` command task key and override it, but didn't success. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think the name is used for publishing and the id is used internally. Have you tried just using shorter ids while keeping the names as they are?

Comment: This is a good suggestion and you should make it a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create a dedicated object, with its own Scala file, that would define a def Project.

That way you could have something like:

`[your company].scala`:

```
object <your company> {
  def Project(name: String = "", path: sbt.File, dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq.empty, isCompanyProject: Boolean = true) = {
    val settings = ...
    val projectName = if (companyProject) {
      ... // [your company / your project / whatever] + "-" + name
    } else name

    val project = sbt.Project(projectName, path, settings = ...)

    project
  }
}
```

in the same folder as your `ApplicationBuild.scala` file:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  ...
  lazy val foo = <your company>.Project("foo", sbt.file("foo"), fooDependencies)
}
```

That way you could create a `[your company]` task that would call `project` with your company's prefix.